# How to show "Run as different user" on Start in Windows 8.1 Update 1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, start-screen

Is it possible to show the "Run as different user" option for applications on Start in Windows 8.1 Update 1?
I have enabled **Show "Run as different user" command on Start** user policy but to no avail. Even restarted the PC after doing a `gpupdate /force`.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @Zoredache No, I didn't :-( Not sure it is possible actually.